# Enable Custom Property field for SItecore General Link Field

Tags: fieldtype, field

While inserting internal link from Sitecore General link field I am seeing Custom Property but that is disabled and not allowing to use it.

How to use that property in Sitecore 10.

Answer (score 1):

If you will select Target value to Custom from the `Target drop-down`. You will be able to enter the Custom Property.

Refer to this image.

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can we add any custom attributes in that Custom Property like data-atrrribute='{} ?'

Comment: I think this is a different question. Let me check. Kindly mark the question accepted if you are able to use the custom property.  @Rahul

Comment: @Rahul I don't think you can add a data attribute to the custom target. It is to use if the target is not present in the target drop down. Like  target="_top".

Comment: Here is something that might help you. https://assurex.co/sitecore/extending-general-link-field-in-sitecore/